# Remove all home screen shortcuts programatically in Android

Tags: android, shortcut

I want to delete all home screen shortcuts in Android programmatically. I have already written an app to create my own shortcuts for opening up a browser instance & directing to specific URI & delete only those programmatically. When deleting shortcuts this way, I have to provide the exact name & URI for each shortcut.

How can I achieve the same thing for existing shortcuts which were not created by me (like browser, calendar or any other app default created a shortcut on home screen)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like something that shouldn't be and probably isn't possible  for security reasons.